# $A ∆ (B ∩ C) = (A ∆ B) ∩ (A ∆ C)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I was wondering.
I found out that the statement is false but I'm not sure..

I got - for some $x$ in the set $A$ ($x$ is not in set $b$ of $c$) it's true.
Same with for some $X$ in $C$ and $B$ but not in $A$ it's true.
But for some $x$ in $A$ and $B$ and not $C$ it's false.
And for some $x$ in $A$ and $C$ and not $B$ it's false.

Which means it's wrong right ? Because it's partially correct..

Do you think any website to check this statements for sure ?

Thank you.

Comment: What does mean by ∆?

Comment: @Subhajit: Symmetric difference.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott Long time no see Sir. Welcome back.

Comment: @Juniven: Thanks!

Comment: One possibly useful way to think about symmetric difference is as follows: if $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are mutually disjoint sets and $A=X_1\cup X_2$, $B=X_2\cup X_3$, then $A\triangle B=X_1\cup X_3$.

Answer (score 4):

I’m afraid that what you wrote is too unclear for me to follow with certainty, but if you’re saying that the equality is false if there is an $x$ that is in $A$ and exactly one of the sets $B$ and $C$, you’re right.

Suppose that $x\in A\cap B$ and $x\notin C$. Then

- $x\notin B\cap C$, so $x\in A\triangle(B\cap C)$, but
- $x\notin A\triangle B$, so $x\notin(A\triangle B)\cap(A\triangle C)$.

Answer (score 0):

The equality you initially state as false is actually true. Let me prove it to you knowing beforehand that set intersection distributes over set difference and set intersection distributes over set union. So we want to see that set intersection also distributes over symmetric difference.

Denoting symmetric difference by $*$, we have:

$({R \cap T}) * ({S \cap T}) = (({R \cap T}) \setminus ({S \cap T})) \cup (({S \cap T}) \setminus ({R \cap T})) = $

$ = (( {R \setminus S}) \cap T) \cup (({S \setminus R) \cap T}) = (({R \setminus S}) \cup ({S \setminus R})) \cap T = $

$= ({R * S}) \cap T$

Proving

$({R \cap S}) * ({R \cap T}) = R \cap ({S * T})$

is a direct consequence of set intersection being commutative.

Comment: Yes but it's A * ( B ∩ C) = (A * B) ∩ (A * C).                 So I get a false response for X in A and B but not C.          And X in A and C but not B.                                          So it's not always true which means the statement is false.